# nginx website is extraordinarily slow but only for my network

Tags: performance, webserver, nginx

My personal website has been extremely slow for only me and my network. If i connect to it via cellular data on my phone, or a laptop at another building, it is as fast as any other website, but when i connect from any device connected to the network that the website is running from, it takes from 0.3 seconds (normal time) to upwards of 3 minutes to load any page, but that 0.3 second load time only occurs once per session. Sometimes it doesnt load at all, and just times out.

my nginx.conf has been provided below:

```
# nginx.conf

worker_processes 5;
error_log logs/error.log;
pid       logs/nginx.pid;
worker_rlimit_nofile 8192;

events {
    worker_connections  4096;
    use poll;
    accept_mutex on;
    multi_accept on;
}


http {
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    include mime.types;
    access_log  logs/access.log;
    keepalive_timeout 75s;
    keepalive_requests 100000;
    server_names_hash_bucket_size 128; # this seems to be required for some vhosts
    client_max_body_size 100k;
    proxy_read_timeout 1;
    proxy_buffering off;
    ssl_session_cache   shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_timeout 10m;
    
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    upstream files {
        zone upstreams 64K;
        server 127.0.0.1:2025 max_fails=1 fail_timeout=5s;
        keepalive 2;
    }

    server {
    
        #listen 80;
    
        listen 443 ssl;
        ssl_certificate C:/Certbot/live/website.gov/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key C:/Certbot/live/website.gov/privkey.pem;
        
        server_name website.gov;
        
    
        location /fs/ {
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
        }
        
        location /files/ {
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_pass http://files/;
        }
    
        location / {
            root html;
        }
        
        location /e/ {
            add_header Content-Type text/plain;
            return 200 $remote_addr;
        }
        
        location /movies/ {
            alias E:/movies/;
            autoindex on; #Show table of contents
            autoindex_exact_size off; #Show file size
            autoindex_localtime on; #Show file time
        }
        
        location /music/ {
            alias E:/memes_and_dumb_garbage/private/music/;
            autoindex on; #Show table of contents
            autoindex_exact_size off; #Show file size
            autoindex_localtime on; #Show file time
        }
        
    }
    
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
}
```

most of these directives were provided by forums, as this problem has persisted for months now. i've researched into them, but i dont really have a good understanding of their importance or what scale they're for, e.g tiny website with few visitors like mine, a moderately sized website like superuser.com, or a monolithic website like google.com

any help would be greatly appreciated. thanks
(edited to remove private info)

Comment: You should try to see what URL is making the problem. Load the page. Press F12 ( developer mode ) > 'Network' tab > check both "Preserve log" and "disable cache" > Reload the page.

Comment: "disable cache" worked a bit, but most reloads still take a long time. [heres a screeenshot](https://i.imgur.com/slufcvP.png) of which urls are the problem and it seems to be the base url which is "blocked" for 3 seconds.